# Kubernetes: How to mount volumes into Windows pods?

Tags: windows, kubernetes

I set up a small Kubernetes cluster for testing, and for storage I use glusterfs. No CSI, I just create the volumes manually for now.

Now, I added a Windows node to the cluster. It works fine so far, but I can't get any volumes to mount in the container.

I did a very simple pod definition:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: windows-test
  labels:
    name: windows-test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: sample
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: "1.0"
          memory: "1Gi"
      command:
        - cmd
        - "/c"
        - "dir"
        - "/s"
        - 'c:\'
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "foo"
          name: testvol
  nodeSelector:
    "kubernetes.io/os": windows
  volumes:
    - name: testvol
      glusterfs:
        path: wintest
        endpoints: glusterfs-cluster
        readOnly: false
```

When I run this, the pod never starts and when I describe it, I get:

```
  Warning  FailedMount  <invalid>                      kubelet, node09    MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "testvol" : mount failed: only cifs mount is supported now, fstype: "glusterfs", mounting source ("10.93.111.35:wintest"), target ("c:\\var\\lib\\kubelet\\pods\\6d207138-09fb-4e1f-86e7-6a71cef5ce7e\\volumes\\kubernetes.io~glusterfs\\testvol"), with options (["auto_unmount" "backup-volfile-servers=10.93.111.31:10.93.111.32:10.93.111.33:10.93.111.34:10.93.111.35:10.93.111.36:10.93.111.37:10.93.111.38" "log-file=\\var\\lib\\kubelet\\plugins\\kubernetes.io\\glusterfs\\testvol\\windows-test-glusterfs.log" "log-level=ERROR"]), the following error information was pulled from the glusterfs log to help diagnose this issue: could not open log file for pod windows-test
```

It seems that Windows pods do not support glusterfs, but only "cifs". Can anyone guide me how to mount a volume via cifs? The only information I found in the docs was about the `azure-file` storage but I couldn't figure out if that can also mount CIFS shares on-prem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could start with [this](https://github.com/fstab/cifs).

### CIFS Flexvolume Plugin for Kubernetes

**Installing**

> The flexvolume plugin is a single shell script named [cifs](https://github.com/fstab/cifs). This shell script must be available on the Kubernetes master and on each of the Kubernetes nodes. By default, Kubernetes searches for third party volume plugins in /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec/. The plugin directory can be configured with the kubelet's --volume-plugin-dir parameter, run ps aux | grep kubelet to learn the location of the plugin directory on your system (see #1). The cifs script must be located in a subdirectory named fstab~cifs/. The directory name fstab~cifs/ will be mapped to the Flexvolume driver name fstab/cifs.
>
> On the Kubernetes master and on each Kubernetes node run the following commands:

```
VOLUME_PLUGIN_DIR="/usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec"
mkdir -p "$VOLUME_PLUGIN_DIR/fstab~cifs"
cd "$VOLUME_PLUGIN_DIR/fstab~cifs"
curl -L -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fstab/cifs/master/cifs
chmod 755 cifs
```

> The cifs script requires a few executables to be available on each host system:
>
> mount.cifs, on Ubuntu this is in the [cifs-utils](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/cifs-utils) package.
> jq, on Ubuntu this is in the [jq](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/jq) package.
> mountpoint, on Ubuntu this is in the [util-linux](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/util-linux) package.
> base64, on Ubuntu this is in the [coreutils](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/coreutils) package.
> To check if the installation was successful, run the following command:

```
VOLUME_PLUGIN_DIR="/usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec"
$VOLUME_PLUGIN_DIR/fstab~cifs/cifs init
```

> It should output a JSON string containing "status": "Success". This command is >also run by Kubernetes itself when the cifs plugin is detected on the file system.

**Running**

> The plugin takes the CIFS username and password from a [Kubernetes Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/). To create the secret, you first have to convert your username and password to base64 encoding:

```
echo -n username | base64
echo -n password | base64
```

> Then, create a file secret.yml and use the ouput of the above commands as username and password:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: cifs-secret
  namespace: default
type: fstab/cifs
data:
  username: 'ZXhhbXBsZQ=='
  password: 'bXktc2VjcmV0LXBhc3N3b3Jk'
```

> Apply the secret:

```
kubectl apply -f secret.yml
```

> You can check if the secret was installed successfully using kubectl describe secret cifs-secret.
>
> Next, create a file pod.yml with a test pod (replace //server/share with the network path of your CIFS share):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    volumeMounts:
    - name: test
      mountPath: /data
  volumes:
  - name: test
    flexVolume:
      driver: "fstab/cifs"
      fsType: "cifs"
      secretRef:
        name: "cifs-secret"
      options:
        networkPath: "//server/share"
        mountOptions: "dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0644,noperm"
```

> Start the pod:

```
kubectl apply -f pod.yml
```

> You can verify that the volume was mounted successfully using kubectl describe pod busybox.

---

Additionally there is another [github tutorial](https://github.com/juliohm1978/kubernetes-cifs-volumedriver) with Kubernetes CIFS Volume Driver.

---

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: This is almost correct, but you have to use a Windows version of the CIFS Flexvolume plugin. Microsoft provides one: https://github.com/microsoft/K8s-Storage-Plugins/tree/master/flexvolume/windows I mark it as the correct answer as the procedure you outlined works.